# Where can I add the 'timeupdate' event when working with a-frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to set a timeupdate event to an audio I loaded like this

```
<a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <audio id="audio" src="">
      </a-assets>
        <a-sound id="vr-audio" src="#audio" autoplay="true" position="0 0 0"></a-sound>
    </a-scene>
```

I've tried to do it like this, and with the #audio tag but no luck...

```
var vr_audio = document.querySelector( "#vr-audio" );
    vr_audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
     console.log('time-update');
   });
```

I'm reading the **src** audio from a blob

Comment: What browser? Can you share link to reproduce on glitch? https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but more errors came in, thanks for looking at this, I got the event from the <audio> in the assets... it wasn't the event I was looking for though...